# Excel, split cell after first space

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is possible to split cell after first space?

```
ID;name;city street;phone;
51;Joe;Paris Sezame street;77755566;
52;John;Prague Under Bridge;666555444;
53;Helen;Tokio 3.st;66554455;
```

Like

```
ID;name;city; street;phone;
51;Joe;Paris; Sezame street;77755566;
52;John;Prague; Under Bridge;666555444;
53;Helen;Tokio; 3.st;66554455;
```

Comment: You just want to insert a semi-colon before the first space?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SUBSTITUTE` function. In another column enter this and fill down to the last row.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","; ",1)
```

Here `A1` is the first cell with data.